# Difference between Firebase Admin SDK and Firebase Admin Web API

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to take a decision to use Firebase Admin SDK or Firebase Admin REST API.

I need to use it in the communication from Angular/Node.js to Firebase database.

Please let me know if you can share the comparison between this two.

Thanks.

Answer (score 16):

For communicating from an Angular web app with the Firebase Database, use the [Firebase Web SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup).

For communicating from a server-side Node.js process with the Firebase Database, use the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup).

For communicating with the Firebase Database from a platform for which there is no SDK, use the [Firebase REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/start).

Comment: So what if we are using a mean stack app? Which one to use the web one or the server one?